# How to perform groupby and show data for specific column values using pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Please find a **sample** data

```
country  total_funding_usd      sectors
--------------------------------------------
USA         2000000             education
USA         120000              Medical
USA         8000000             Retail
IND         290000              Retail
IND         120000              Medical
CHINA       1100000             Healthcare
CHINA       120000              Medical
AUS         1100000             Retail
AUS         8000000             Medical
AUS         700000              Healthcare
```

Query:- wants to see the top 2 countries which have received the highest
total funding (for the sectors Medical, Retail)?

I could do groupby but neither I could print just top 2 countries nor for selected sectors . It's showing all records. All I tried is as below. Please help

```
master_frame.groupby('country')['total_funding_usd'].max().head()
```

**expected output:**

```
country       sectors   total_funding_usd 
——————————————————————-------------------

USA     Medical        120000   
        Retail         8000000  

AUS     Medical        8000000
        Retail         1100000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering, then aggregate `sum` and get top2 countries by [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and filter again with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df2 = df[df['sectors'].isin(['Medical','Retail'])]

idx = df2.groupby('country')['total_funding_usd'].sum().nlargest(2).index

df3 = df2[df2['country'].isin(idx)]
print (df3)
  country  total_funding_usd  sectors
1     USA             120000  Medical
2     USA            8000000   Retail
7     AUS            1100000   Retail
8     AUS            8000000  Medical
```

**Details**:

```
print (df2.groupby('country')['total_funding_usd'].sum())
country
AUS      9100000
CHINA     120000
IND       410000
USA      8120000
Name: total_funding_usd, dtype: int64

print (df2.groupby('country')['total_funding_usd'].sum().nlargest(2))
country
AUS    9100000
USA    8120000
Name: total_funding_usd, dtype: int64

print (df2.groupby('country')['total_funding_usd'].sum().nlargest(2).index)
Index(['AUS', 'USA'], dtype='object', name='country')
```

Comment: got the idea about helpful function but still not able to produce output as I mentioned(updated) in the question. I personally think this should be the format for(top 2 countries which have received the highest total funding (for the sectors Medical, Retail)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. I used step wise process suggested by at my original data frame and got the desired output